# JS select validity when required and disabled

Tags: javascript, validation

There is something strange with JS field validity, a can't find informations about it.

When a text input is required but disabled and empty, `validity.valid` is true.

When a select in required, disabled, and no option is selected, `validity.valid` is false.

Do you know is this is normal ? Shoud I remove `required` in addition to adding `disabled` ?

Comment: Can't reproduce that, they should both be valid as disabled inputs aren't submitted, and shouldn't affect the forms validity -> http://jsfiddle.net/eoxcosky/

Comment: you can use readonly instead of disabled

Comment: Thanks for this, now I understand. I'm using the jQuery chosen plugin. It's adding an empty option as a placeholder,  and this empty option seems to be invalid.